# API post request taking a lot of time in Python using requests module as compared to Postman

Tags: python, api, rest

I am trying to make a post API call with bearer token using the Python requests module but I observed that it is taking almost 1 hour to give me the response and Postman takes 3 minutes for the same request. Not getting the root cause for this and I am searching for an alternative to avoid this. Below is my code.

```
def trigger_L3_validation_api(run_id, env, running_locally):
    print('triggering the L3 API')
    token = generate_bearer_token(env, running_locally)
    api_url = "abccd/market-data/validation/level-three"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token + ""}
    reqbody = {

        "institutionalRunId": run_id,

        "ownershipRunId": run_id,

        "f13InstRunId": run_id,

        "entityType": "FREE_FLOAT_FACTOR"

    }
    response = requests.post(api_url, json=reqbody, headers=headers).json()
    print(response.content)
```

When I tried to debug, the code gets stuck at line **response = requests.post(api_url, json=reqbody, headers=headers).json()**. Any other way we can hit the post request for the response time equal to the Postman time?

Comment: If you call `.json()`, then `response` will be a list or dictionary, it won't have a `.content` attribute.

Comment: What happens if you don't call `.json()`? How large is the content? It may be very huge and take a long time to load the JSON.

Comment: The requests module is super fast and it is used in countless applications. It is highly unlikely that it is the culprit here. I suggest that you split the problem by moving `generate_bearer_token` outside the function `trigger_L3_validation_api` and ditch `.json()` and `response.content`. Are you using https (broken certificate validation configuration could play a factor). +IMO, having a 3 minute long request in your design is just begging for trouble.